# Python script not executing properly in cron

Tags: python, mysql, cron

I am having a problem with the python script that I am trying to automate in cron. I belive that the problem is in the mysql module not being imported when running the script through cron.

I tried different solution in the net but none of them seems to be working.

Btw, the script is running normal when executing in terminal

Here is my crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
#MAILTO=root
# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/testlist.py > /var/log/test.log 2>&1
```

and here is the error generated in test.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/testlist.py", line 106, in <module>
if  __name__ =='__main__':main()
File "/var/www/html/testlist.py", line 104, in main
get_ec2_instances('us-west-1')
File "/var/www/html/testlist.py", line 90, in get_ec2_instances
insert_metric(d[u'Timestamp'],d[u'Average'],d[u'Unit'])
File "/var/www/html/testlist.py", line 49, in insert_metric
cursor.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment
```

and here is the part of the script that causing the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
import boto.ec2
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch
import datetime
import json
import ast
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from mysql_connect import read_db_config

def insert_metric(timestamp,average,unit):
    print "Inserting now"
    query = "INSERT INTO metrics_tbl(timestamp,average,unit) " \
            "VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
    args = (timestamp,average,unit)

    try:
        db_config = read_db_config()
        conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, args)

        if cursor.lastrowid:
            print('last insert id', cursor.lastrowid)
        else:
            print('last insert id not found')

        conn.commit()
    except Error as error:
        print(error)

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: An exception occurred in the `try`-suite. So `cursor` was not successfully defined. The error message should have been printed in `/var/log/test.log`. What does it say?

Comment: the error is posted above. It is about UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment. I am getting the same error when I simulate, removing the import mysql.connector then execute the script in shell.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `try`, `except`, `finally` lines, dedent the code inside and just run the code "bare"? Then you should see in `test.log` the traceback  error message of the true originating exception.

Comment: Thank you! I got the real culprit when i remove the `try`, `except`, `finally`. The problem is in the mysql_connector.py. I wasn't able to defined the config file using its absolute path. Thank you @unutbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the traceback ??? The problem is quite clear: in your `finally` clause, you're trying to access the name `cursor` while it's not yet defined.

Look at your code: you're defining `cursor` at the third line of the `try` block - so until your code reaches that point, the name `cursor` does not exists. Now if one of the two first statements raises and exception, you end up in the `finally` block, where you try to access `cursor`...

```
try:
     db_config = read_db_config()
     conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute(query, args)

     if cursor.lastrowid:
         print('last insert id', cursor.lastrowid)
     else:
         print('last insert id not found')

     conn.commit()
 except Error as error:
     print(error)

 finally:
     cursor.close()
     conn.close()
```

To solve this (first) problem, you need to either have a narrower try block and/or define `cursor` (and `conn`) before the try block.

First, extract the call to `read_db_config` from the try block - you don't need it here. If it fails, you'll have a traceback anyway... Then define `conn` and `cursor` to `None` before the try block so you don't have a `NameError` in the finally block, and, in the finally block, test whether `cursor` and `conn` have been opened before closing them. Also, your `except` clause is more than useless - it prevents you from getting the full traceback (which is invaluable for debugging), so just remove it and let the exception propagate:

```
conn = None
cursor = None
db_config = read_db_config()

try:
     conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute(query, args)
     if cursor.lastrowid:
         print('last insert id', cursor.lastrowid)
     else:
         print('last insert id not found')
     conn.commit()
finally:
    if cursor is not None:
        cursor.close()
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Now you can run your code again and this time find out what's the REAL problem (which obviously has nothing to do with importing MySQLdb - else you'd get an `ImportError` right up from the start and your code wouldn't even be called).

Comment: Thank you, I got the real cause of the problem. The problem is in the mysql_connector.py. I wasn't able to define the config file in the script using its absolute path. Thank you.